# Gradle Multiproject - Better dependency control

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I got a multi module project with an arbitrary number of `spring-boot rest services` which all run on their own `embedded tomcat` and some web frontends which it self must not contain any business logic. These will be configured as `Zuul` proxies and therefore do not need any other dependencies.

So in my top level `build.gradle` I can declare all dependencies which are common to all projects which in that case would be `spring-boot-starter` and `log4j`. Though all the rest services share nearly all their dependencies.

**Is there a way to cluster dependencies? So I can say you are a frontend with minimal dependencies and you are a basic `JPA` project?**

I know I could define dependencies for all separate but then it's doubled in many files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [official user guide's](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:how_to_declare_your_dependencies) "How to declare your dependencies", chapter 52.4.8. "Optional attributes". According to it, you are able to combine dependencies into some collections, which could be applied as project dependencies, as:

```
List groovy = ["org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.4@jar",
               "commons-cli:commons-cli:1.0@jar",
               "org.apache.ant:ant:1.9.4@jar"]
List hibernate = ['org.hibernate:hibernate:3.0.5@jar',
                  'somegroup:someorg:1.0@jar']
dependencies {
    runtime groovy, hibernate
}
```

So, you can create in the root build script a number of dependencies groups for different configurations (I mean one for frontend, one for JPA project and etc.). And then the only thing you need, is to apply this groups to the subprojects, which are of the reauired type.

Comment: Looks pretty much like what I needed :). Is there also a way to embed exclusions in there if I don't want fo example `group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-webmvc'` in my jpa projects but need other stuff boot provides?

Comment: @DennisIch not really sure, whether it's possible to provide excludes within the list, but then you apply some groups of dependencies to the project, you may try to modify it's configuration, like `configurations {
    compile.exclude group:'org.hamcrest'
}` to exclude something from all the configuration

Comment: Ok thought so ... Cannot have all I suppose but helps a lot already. Thanks for the input.